# Does whoever Lord is in James 1:7 refer to whomever God is in James 1:5?

Tags: greek, james

James 1:5, 7

> <sup>**5**</sup> If any of you lacks wisdom, let him ask **God**, who gives generously to all without reproach, and it will be given him.
>
> <sup>**7**</sup> For that person must not suppose that he will receive anything from the **Lord**;

Using Greek and contextual clues does Lord in James 1:7 refer to God in James 1:5. No matter what take we have for the moment of what Lord or God means doctrinally. This is a companion to my previous question but it does not tie itself to James 1:1 for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James 1:5-7

> <sup>**5**</sup> If any of you lacks wisdom, let him ask **God**, who gives generously to all without reproach, and it will be given him. <sup>**6**</sup> But let **him** ask in faith, with no doubting, for the one who doubts is like a wave of the sea that is driven and tossed by the wind. <sup>**7**</sup> For **that person** must not suppose that he will receive anything from the **Lord**;

It seems clear here that "him" in James 1:6 is asking "God" from James 1:5.

In James 1:7, "that person" must be one of the "him"s who are asking in faith from James 1:6. So context seems to indicate that the Lord from James 1:7 is the same as God from James 1:5

Comment: @agarza thanks for the editing help.

Comment: If you are asking whether the reference to God in verse 5 is the same being as the Lord in vs. 7, Paul refers to God as the Father, and the Lord as Jesus Christ the Son. (I Thes. 1:1, Eph. 1:1)  That's typically what is meant in the New Testament by other writers also, see Hebr. 1:1-2.